# Components to record ultrasonic sound? Up to 200kHz

Tags: sound, ultrasound

For a personal project, I’m trying to record ultrasonic sound. I would like to find the best way to record from 20kHz to 200kHz.

As I found from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasound), animals can hear up to 200kHz.

As I prefer to design my own board, the best component I have found is this [Knowles SPH0641LU4H-1](https://www.mouser.fr/ProductDetail/Knowles/SPH0641LU4H-1?qs=ueBQf%252BU%252Bi5RrGzOCJCKX0Q%3D%3D).

But the range is from 50Hz to 80kHz...

What is the best configurations/components to record ultrasonic sound?

Comment: You're question can't be understood without following links. It should contain enough information that the question can stand on its own - even after the links die. Can you improve it by adding an image and the essential details from the specification?

Comment: Look at senscomp transducers. 20 to 100kHz. You will need a high voltage bias supply. You might need multiple microphones to cover the frequency range